# Should I delete answers with no votes?

Tags: discussion, answers

Assuming that I had answered a question and didn't get any votes(up or down) for a month or some weeks, should I worry about delete it? I mean, should I assume that it is a bad answer as well if it was down voted?

I'm questioning it because I can see that there are a lot questions on SU with a high number of useless answers that didn't got any votes and are just "accumulating garbage" on SU and I would just like to create a discussion about it.

Comment: If you leave it long enough, people sometimes notice it and drop some rep on you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the answer is right or useful but has no votes, leave it be.

If the answer is wrong or not helpful and you don't want it to be there, click delete.

If another answer on the question has the same content and yours doesn't add anything new, feel free to delete.

Comment: you can also edit your good answers to make them *MORE AWESOME* which bumps the question and potentially gets more eyeballs on your awesome-but-not-upvoted-enough-yet answer.

Answer (score 3):

Taking your question title literal, I would say *no!* or else I would have to delete 200 of my answers...

**No votes doesn't mean the answer is bad**, it could've been helpful to a one-time visitor who doesn't have a way to vote on your answer. I would only really remove my answers when they accumulate down-votes over time, because in that case they do result in noise.